# Process Management Solution

Tags: java, c++, deployment, process

I'm working on a project that requires a process management solution much like init.d but with the following requirements:

1) Working with Windows not Linux
2) Must be able to start/stop/restart programs written in heterogeneous languages.
3) Must be able to extend process manager to start / stop processes depending on run-mode information obtained from remote-host over pub/sub interface (most likely DDS).

Ideally we would want this in Java, but can be C / C++. Also, the process manager must be fail safe (I assume running in a service with auto-restart on fail will be enough).

I could write my own implementation for scratch, but we have a unreasonably tight schedule, so obviously an already developed solution is preferable.

Michael

Comment: We have also tight schedule to answer the reasonable questions.. So don't ask like this?

Comment: @Venkats - From my understanding, the OP is interested in an existing library of some sort, he didn't ask us to write it for him.

Comment: @Venkats - I am trying to find a solution that we can integrate and modify if necessary. As IVlad has stated, I am not asking anything unreasonable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I simply bootstrapped my processes with a Windows service wrapper and manually managed their lifecycle programatically with windows APIs for services.